# Limitation of participants Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to create a registration form for a series of lectures participants could sign up for. However, depending on the lecture, there is a different limitation of numbers of participants that can sign up for it.

So far, I found the [course registration template](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AjbZnjlHMPF0dEtpcTYxRlQ5UlpXZWtiV3JuRDBHYUE&mode=public#), however it does not allow to use it with the "checkboxes" but only with "choose from the list" question type. In the registration form I try to create, they should be able to choose more than one option (therefore use the question type "checkboxes" instead of "choose from a list").

Do you know if there is any possibility in Google Docs to specify a limited number of participants for each lecture?

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Google Forms doesn't include a limit on the number of responses as built-in feature but you could extend the of Google Docs editors features though add-ons or Google Apps Script.

## Alternatives

### [formLimiter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formlimiter/clflahnkjeannplpafofekagclpmijkl)

From: https://sites.google.com/a/newvisions.org/scripts_resources/add-ons/formlimiter

> formLimiter automatically sets Google Forms to stop accepting
> responses after a maximum number of responses, at a specific date and
> time, or when a spreadsheet cell contains a specified value.
>
> Great for time-bound assignments, event registrations with limited
> seats, or other first-come, first-served signup scenarios.

## References

[Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)